# Keyboard when lose focus BasicTextField Android Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to know if it is possible that when a BasicTextField has the focus and the keyboard is up, when I put it after an action of a button for example, enabled to false to that BasicTextField, that the keyboard is not hidden.

I tried to use the readOnly attribute but it hides the keyboard.

Thanks

Comment: Provide code snippets to help you more.